# select highest correlated pairs from a matrix SAS

Tags: arrays, select, macros, sas, select-into

I have a dataset like this

```
data have;
    do i = 1 to 1000;
    y = ranuni(0);
    x1 = y ** 2;
    x2 = x1 ** 3;
    x3 = x2 - x1/2;
    output;
    end;
run;
```

I build a correlation matrix like this:

```
proc corr
    data = have
    out = correlation_matrix
        (where = (_TYPE_ = "CORR"))
    noprint;
run;
```

I've attempted to think out loud some code which would achieve something similar to what I'm looking for, the syntax nor the logic is correct but I'm having a go at describing what I'm looking for

```
proc sort
    data = correlation_matrix
    by _NAME_;
run;

data _temp;
    set correlation_matrix;
    array col[*] _numeric_;

    by _NAME_;

    do i = 1 to dim(col);
        if col(i) > 0.6 then do;
            %let list = append(vname(col));
    end;
run;
```

And from the correlation matrix, I'm looking for a way to return pairs which have a correlation of 60% or is above some threshold, the pairs I will then use to build scatter plot / histogram matrices like this

```
proc contents;
    data = high_correlation_pairs
    out  = contents
    noprint;
run;

proc sort
    data = contents
    nodupkey;
    by name;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select name INTO: highly_correlated_pairs
        separated by " "
            from contents
;
quit;

ODS GRAPHICS /
        IMAGEMAP=OFF;
OPTIONS VALIDVARNAME=ANY;
    PROC SGSCATTER 
        DATA=have;
        TITLE "Scatter Plot Matrix";
        FOOTNOTE;
        MATRIX &highly_correlated_pairs
                / 
                DIAGONAL=(HISTOGRAM  )
                START=TOPLEFT
                NOLEGEND
    ;
    RUN;
TITLE; FOOTNOTE;
```

I'm just unsure how to select variables from the matrix which have a pair of over 60% correlation, it could even by a by *NAME* return the columns with corr over 60%

Answer (score 1):

You can get the pairs like this - the key is the `vname` function, which returns the name of an array element:

```
data high_corrs;
  set correlation_matrix;
  array coefs i--x3;
  length var1 var2 $32.;
  do j = 1 to dim(coefs);
    corr = coefs(j);
    if _n_ < j and corr > 0.6 then do;
      var1 = vname(coefs(_n_));
      var2 = vname(coefs(j));
      output;
    end;
  end;
  keep var1 var2 corr;
run;
```

Perhaps from there you can work out the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: to include complete answer:

PROC TRANSPOSE is used to transpose the correlation matric to x,y pairs and subset to correlations of interest.  A macro variable is created to use in PROC SGSCATTER.

NOTE: PLOTREQUESTS=x1*x2 x1*y x2*x3 x2*y

```
data have;
   do i = 1 to 1000;
      y = ranuni(0);
      x1 = y ** 2;
      x2 = x1 ** 3;
      x3 = x2 - x1/2;
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc corr data=have out=corr noprint;
   run;
proc transpose name=with data=corr out=pair(where=(.6 le abs(col1) lt 1));
   where _type_ eq 'CORR';
   by _name_ notsorted;
   run;
data pairV / view=pairv;
   set pair;
   call sortc(_name_,with);
   run;
proc sort data=pairv out=pair2 nodupkey;
   by _name_ with;
   run;
proc sql noprint;
   select catx('*',_name_,with) into :plotrequests separated by ' ' from pair2;
   quit;
%put NOTE: &=plotrequests;
proc sgscatter data=have;
   plot &plotrequests;
   run;
   quit;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll start building on this